# Why is my method not working?

Tags: c#

I have a form with a `listView`, which is populated by calling the `showCheckedInFiles()` method. The method works perfectly fine when I add a simple button to the form and press it, which calls the method, but when I call the method from elsewhere it will not populate my `listview`.

Please help it's driving me insane. The first method below is called from another class and that is shown underneath this, and I've included the button method as well for reference, as I say, the button works perfectly, but i need to be able to call the method without clicking a button!!:

```
public void openProject(string projectname)
{
    projectName = projectname;
    string userDir = CSDBpath + projectname + "\\checkedOUT\\" + userName;
    if (!Directory.Exists(userDir)) //Does the user's directory exist, if not, create it
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(userDir);
    }
    showCheckedInFiles();
 }

 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    showCheckedInFiles();
 }
```

The method which calls the above:

```
private void buttonOpenProject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection mySelectedItems;
     mySelectedItems = listView1.SelectedItems;
     Form1 mainform = new Form1();
     string myProject = "";

     foreach (ListViewItem item in mySelectedItems)
     {
         myProject = item.Text;
     }

     mainform.openProject(myProject);
     //mainform.showCheckedInFiles();
     this.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Is the event not firing. I am kind of lost, have you debugged your code. Sometimes a simple debugging can solve complex problems

Comment: You don't run `Show` on your form as far as I can see

Comment: Side note - you're using `projectname` when it looks like you mean to use `projectName` when initializing `userDir` in `openProject(...)`. You can avoid confusion and redundancy by getting rid of `projectName` altogether, assuming you're not using it elsewhere.

Comment: another Side note : you don't need that `foreach` since you are overwriting myProject in every iteration.

Comment: As @Fire-Dragon-DoL noticed, you never show the form so how do you know it's not geting populated? Also you do a foreach on mySelectedItems and on each you set myProject to the item's text, ending with JUST the text for the last item. Why not just get the text on the last item then? And are you sure that text is a valid projectName? Debug is your friend

Comment: @Sam and AbZy - beat me to it there

Comment: @537mfb you had a better explanation :)

Answer (score 5):

In `buttonOpenProject_Click` you create a new hidden instance of `Form1` which is not related to apparently already existing one which is already shown.

Comment: Yeah i've been debugging virtually all day trying to work out what's going on. I only listed a couple of methods in the hope that you guys might show me where i was making a school boy error. But it seems it's not quite that obvious. I'll have to perhaps list more code in the hope somebody can help, it's driving me mad. I'll do that tomorrow as don't have access now.

Comment: @ Abzy - yeah i guessed that foreach was a waste of time particularly as the user should only select one item from the list, but i couldn't immediately work out how to convert a collection to just the selected item, so i used that as a workaround for the mean time. I don't think that's my issue though is it.

Answer (score 0):

Move the ShowCheckInFiles method to a seperate class and as a parameter pass in the listview.  That should allow you to use the method regardless of where you are calling it.

for example...

SomeClass.ShowCheckInFIles(listview1);